# How to apply CSS to specific children of an element

Tags: javascript, css, scss-lint

I have this CSS and looking for a smarter/better way to write this.

```
daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-sm.btn-secondary,
daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-default.btn-info,
daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-sm.btn-info,
daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-sm{
    padding: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

Mayble I should put `daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td` in a variable?

From other similar question on StackOverflow I understand I can use universal selectors but don't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: can you please share the HTML code

Comment: You can either add a unique class to all of these elements and target it that way or you can narrow it down by removing the nested parent elements and go with `daypicker > button` if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: `daypicker` isn't an element-type, it's probably either a class-name or an id; in which case you need to write either `.daypicker` (if a class-name) or `#daypicker` (if an id).

Comment: I'm using this library in my angular project.
https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

using bootstrap v.4 and need to make some changes to the css.

this is the html:
    <datepicker *ngIf="showDate" [(ngModel)]="formattedValue" (ngModelChange)="onPickerChange()" [showWeeks]="showWeeks" [datepickerMode]="datepickerMode"
        [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [dateDisabled]="dateDisabled"></datepicker>

Comment: daypicker is an element I installed from github, I have no access to it so I can't add a class to the relevant elements.

The above css works but I'm looking for a way to enhance it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated the answer as per the comment**

The snippet in your **Q** has `button.btn` in common so you can just use that but as per your comment you don't need this style on `button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger` in this case you can work with this solutions :

**#1**

```
 .daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn:not(.btn-danger){
    padding: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
 }
```

This CSS would select all the `button.btn` elements except the one(s) with a class of .btn-danger. [Refer link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

**#2**

```
.daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn{
    padding: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}


/*the style below will reset to your need for .btn-danger*/;

.daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-danger{
   padding: /*your desired size*/;
   font-size: /*your desired size*/;
}
```

It's up to you to use the one which is apt for your requirement. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not what I had in mind but works perfectly.
Thanks.

Comment: @Shay What was the idea in your mind share it. we can try your method also.!

Comment: you'r solution is wider then my snippet, It will effect elements other the ones I intended.

Comment: `daypicker` is actually a nodeName, not a className.

Comment: @Shay changind `.daypicker` back to `daypicker` should solve most of you problem with the buttons. If it's not, than you have to keep the verbose definitions of wich buttons you want to select. BUT the `>table>tbody>tr>td>` part is definitely obsolete and can be replaced by a simple *space*.

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean changing this: daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-sm.btn-secondary 
to this:
daypicker>*>button.btn.btn-sm.btn-secondary ?
Because I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Shay please specify what elements you are targeting in your **Q** my first solution works exactly what you will get applying your snippet.

Comment: @weBer you'r code works on all buttons inside the table and not only on the specific buttons as the snippet in my question.
I wanted to know if I write a cleaner code to do exactly the same.

Comment: @Shay in the snippet in your **Q** has `button.btn` in common so you can just use my first suggestion and your result will be same if there is **no common class** then your method is good to go.

Comment: @weBar you'r suggestion effects also the following element:
daypicker>table>tbody>tr>td>button.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger

but I don't want to effect this specific button.

Comment: @Shay you should have mentioned that on your **Q** bro. only then we can suggest best answer for you. I will update my answer according to your need.

Comment: @Shay I have updated the answer for you if it was helpful don't forget to vote it up :)

Comment: @weBar thanks alot.
I can't up vote because I'm new in Stack Overflow and don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @Shay it's k bro. Glad I could help you. :)